# Большое число округляется. Что делать?

Tags: javascript

Пытаюсь передать ajax-oм на сервер id: 2344546087312224. В итоге число округляется до 2344546087312220. Как с этим бороться?

Я получаю данные в формате JSON путём отправки get Ajax запроса при заходе на страницу, изначально приходит айдишник вот такой `"id":"23445460873122244"`, после этого я их отправляю в шаблон:

```
const template = data => `<p onclick="delete(${data.id})">${data.id}</p>`
const result = array.map(template)
```

в шаблоне отображается нормальный id, а в delete улетает округленное число:

```
function(id) {
    alert(id) // Вместо "2344546087312224" получаю 2344546087312220
}
```

Comment: Использовать длинную арифметику.

Comment: попробуйте использовать [bigInt](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/BigInt)

Comment: Передавайте в виде строки.

Comment: @Igor, только хотел написать =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
const template = data => `<p onclick="delete('${data.id}')">${data.id}</p>`;
```

Comment: Спасибо большое. Только не понимаю почему изначально там не строка

Comment: @Senbonzakuraa Пожалуйста. Потому что без дополнительных кавычек в `onclick` получается выражение `delete(123456789)`, а с кавычками `delete('123456789')`. Добавьте, пожалуйста, в вопрос сведения из комментариев, чтобы было понятно, откуда взялся ответ.

Answer (score 2):

Передавайте id в виде строки.

Тип Number (Integer и Float в других языках) предназначен для математических манипуляций. Если это простой идентификатор, который состоит из цифр, как, например, номер телефона, его лучше сохранять как строку. Мы же не добавляем или умножаем номера телефонов и айдишники, верно?

Comment: let id = 23445460873122242;
alert(String(id));
Все равно в таком случае число округляется

Comment: `let id = "23445460873122242"; alert(id);`

Comment: Мне с сервера приходит именно в таком виде в котором я написал, мне нужно самому преобразовывать

Comment: Разве самому парсить тогда ответ сервера. Само число точнее не сделать уже(

Comment: "Мне с сервера приходит именно в таком виде" - ??

Comment: @Igor мне приходят данные с сервера, в данных есть id, вот пришел он в виде числа, на странице отображается нормально а при отправке обратно округляется.

Comment: "мне приходят данные с сервера" - ??

Comment: @Igor, ты не понимаешь как данные могут приходить с сервера или что? Чего ты добиваешься? Я задал конкретный вопрос "Как бороться с округлением?".

Comment: "мне приходят данные с сервера", "а при отправке обратно" - я понятия не имею, что означают эти фразы

Comment: @Senbonzakuraa Как вы данные с сервера получаете? Вряд ли это строго типизированные данные, если только вы не через WCF какой-нибудь работаете. Скорее всего это строки, которые вы сами можете интерпретировать как что хотите.

Comment: @CrazyElf я получаю их в формате JSON отправкой get Ajax запроса при заходе на страницу, изначально приходит айдишник вот такой "id":"23445460873122244", после этого я их отправляю в шаблон:
`const template = data => `<p onclick="delete(${data.id})">${data.id}</p>``
`const result = array.map(template)`
в шаблоне отображается нормальный id, а в delete улетает округленное число

Comment: "а в delete улетает округленное число" - не может быть. Что есть "улетает"?

Comment: @Igor в функцию delete при клике я передаю id, 
`function delete(id){ alert(id) }`
тут получаю округленное число

Comment: @Senbonzakuraa Ну попробуйте что-нибудь типа delete('${data.id}'), может тогда в delete всё же строка прилетит. А, уже есть такой ответ ))

Comment: @CrazyElf спасибо, уже так и сделал по совету Igor